# R assigning array in multivariate Kalman filter

Tags: r, kalman-filter

I can create a multivariate Kalman model as below.
However, I am not sure if I have assigned the array correctly.

```
library("KFAS")

n <- 100
dx <- data.frame(a1=cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)),a2=cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)),a3=cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)),a4=cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)),a5=cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)),a6=cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE)))
tail(dx)
mx <- as.matrix(dx)

Har <- array(rep( 0.01,36*100), c(6, 6, 100));
model1 <- SSModel(mx ~ SSMtrend(1, Q = Har),H=Har)
dkf <- KFS(model1)

dkf
```

Also, the results seem the same as if I run each univariate model separately.
This may be because I have set the array incorrectly.

How can I run the model to include covariates so that there is co-dependence and each of the factors makes a contribution so that the results are an improvement to the individual univariate models?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: maybe you should ask on cross validated, you ll get more chance